# How to find a string with pattern and replace in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Below is the line of code from a file, and I want to replace the `currentVersion` value with something else.

**I have parsed the file and converted to string. only need a way to replace version.**

```
private currentVersion = "1.26.1.3";
```

**Expected output**

```
private currentVersion = "<different version value>";
```

**Note:**

- **Above line occurs once in file.**
- **version value could be anything**

How can it be done with **`regex`** and **`replace`** in Javascript?

Comment: Really _anything_ or in the format `number.number.number.number`?

Comment: Did you try doing this yourself? If so, please share your attempt.

Comment: Replace how? You mean like parse file with source code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @Jamiec it is going to be in `number.number.number.number` format in this file but it would be good not to write a regex depending on that pattern as it may change. Looking for answer that replaces anything assigned to `currentversion` as value. and going to be double quotes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace by captured group

```js
const code = `
import React from "react";

export default App() {
  private currentVersion = "1.2.3.4";
}
`

const replaced = "5.6.7.8"
const res = code.replace(
  /(private currentVersion = ")(.*)(")/gm,
  `$1${replaced}$3`
)

console.log(res)
```